# access to REST in google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am extremely new to GAE sorry if the question is basic but I have been trying for so long
in localhost everything I need works at

```
localhost:8888/rest/users
```

now after deploy, how to access to same resource, I tried:

```
appname.appspot.com/rest/users
```

`appname.appspot.com/_ah/spi/users` but this returns me `bad request 400 {"error_message":"missing /{Service}.{method}"}`

Edit:

This is the starting message:

```
févr. 10, 2017 4:09:43 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value 'D:\Tools\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.9.34\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.34\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from 'D:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp17\MyModandaApp\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
févr. 10, 2017 4:09:44 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
févr. 10, 2017 3:09:47 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: jetty-6.1.x
févr. 10, 2017 3:09:57 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:8888
févr. 10, 2017 3:09:57 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService startHotDeployScanner
INFO: Full scan of the web app in place every 5s.
févr. 10, 2017 3:09:57 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: Module instance default is running at http://localhost:8888/
févr. 10, 2017 3:09:57 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin
févr. 10, 2017 3:09:57 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl doStart
INFO: Dev App Server is now running
févr. 10, 2017 3:20:12 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$2 filesChanged
INFO: A file has changed, reloading the web application.
févr. 10, 2017 3:20:12 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value 'D:\Tools\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.9.34\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.34\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from 'D:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp17\MyModandaApp\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
févr. 10, 2017 3:22:57 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$2 filesChanged
INFO: A file has changed, reloading the web application.
févr. 10, 2017 3:22:57 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value 'D:\Tools\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.9.34\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.34\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from 'D:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp17\MyModandaApp\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
```

Comment: Sometime the app name vs app ID can be confusing. In the GAE Versions page of the cloud console check the URL in the `Version` column and add `/rest/users` to it. https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions

Comment: Can you include in the post the text displayed by the local server when it starts? It should display what it serves at port 8888 - you may need to select the matching specific service/module in the versions page

Comment: @DanCornilescu thanks for your reply , but it shows me : not found

Comment: @DanCornilescu Edited the post

Comment: What do you see in the logs for those requests? https://console.cloud.google.com/logs

Comment: nothing on this link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135417/discussion-between-dan-cornilescu-and-amir).